# Pass list item as input for withColumn (Pyspark)

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Working on a Spark Dataframe where I want to adjust the content of a field. Input for the adjustment comes from a list, however, when I pass the information in the list as arguments I get an error:

> AssertionError: col should be Column

```
fld = ["As_Of_Date","date_format('As_Of_Date,'yyyyMMdd')"]

df.withColumn(fld[0],fld[1])
```

if I pass it directly without the list, it does work. What am I doing wrong and what should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to quote the function `date_format` here.

```
fld = ['As_Of_Date',date_format('As_Of_Date','yyyyMMdd')]
df = df.withColumn(fld[0],fld[1])
```

Comment: check the edit..assignment to the data frame with the transformed column was missing which has been added.